# Pyspark subquery on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark

I have some data that has year, month, date, column_x. The column_x can be missing or not missing. What I want to generate is the missing rate of column_x. In order to do so, I'm trying to create two columns that contains the total row number, which would be total_count, and count column, that represents the column_x == null.

I'm trying to create something like below:

```
total_count | count | year | month | date
60          | 20    | 2022 | 12    | 01
```

so I can do in future `count / total_count` to get some percentage.
However, I'm not sure how I can generate a query.

I tried subqueries but it's throwing me an error.. how can I achieve this through pyspark or sql subqueries? (I can register temp table and run sql queries as well)

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to generate is the missing rate of column_x.

You can do conditional counts. In MySQL:

```
select year, month, day, 
    count(*)              as cnt_total,
    count(column_x)       as cnt_x_not_null,
    sum(column_x is null) as cnt_x_null,
    avg(column_x is null) as ratio_x_null
from mytable
group by year, month, day
```

The last expression (`avg`) gives you the ratio of rows where the column is `null`. This works because MySQL evaluates conditions as 0/1 in numeric context, so we can just use `avg` on top of the `is null` predicate.

Other columns in the resultset give more examples of conditional counts.